# How to use underscore js templates on both server and browser simulatenously

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore templates BOTH on the server and browser, but the browser-side is not working.

I'm using _.templates on the server side when the page is rendered, with the default template delimiters <% %>

I am also trying to use them browser-side, in this case changing the templating delimiters

Here's the code:

```
_.templateSettings = { //use mustache style on browser
              interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
            };

var compile=_.template($('#friend_row').html());
var result=compile({hello: 'hello world'});
```

In the html body I defined the following template:

```
<script id="friend_row" type="text/template">
{{=hello}}
</script>
```

This generates the error:

> SyntaxError: syntax error [Break On This Error]
>
> ((_*t=(=hello))==null?'':*_t)+
>
> underscore-min.js (line 4, col 7)

Comment: why in the world would you change the delimiters between server and browser? Doesn't that defeat the goal of sharing the templates entirely?

Comment: There's ajaxy stuff on the client side that needs templates, and there's templety stuff on the server side.

Comment: I'm not asking why you want to share the template between server and browser, I'm asking why you are changing the delimiters in this case. One template syntax per application is a good, sane practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{=hello}}` is an invalid expression. What goes inside the braces has to be a valid javascript expression, and that is not. You want just `{{hello}}`.

Comment: Things are getting whacky because you're mixing regular underscore syntax with mustache-style interpolation. This is just a silly idea. Here's a working example with regular underscore syntax and using the `print` helper function. Basically, you're confusing the template context data (where you have access to `data`) and a function argument in the template, where you can't access `friend` because it's not part of the template context. http://jsfiddle.net/Gw7KY/